# Why test marked as 'Passed' if it was failed on the "pre-test" stage?

Tags: c#, nunit, automated-tests, nunit-3.0

**I use NUnit 3.0** to run tests.

**My issue is the next:** I have class with tests and in the constructor of this class there is a method that is run before all the tests (because it is in the constructor). While this method is executing there is an error occurs and then I handle it with `CleanUp` method. In the `CleanUp` method I use `TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status` property to look at the status of the test I run.

**The thing is that** the test was not run at all (as pre-condition method was failed). So why this property tells me that the test was passed?

**Here is a piece of my code:**

```
public class DepositSuccessTests
{
        //attributes

        public DepositSuccessTests(string device, WayToPay merchant)
        {    
            SetUp();
            try
            {
                Deposit_Money(merchant); // this method invokes an exception
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                CleanUp();
            }
        }

        [Test]
        //Test that I run but that is not executed because of exception in the constructor
        public void Check_Transaction_Merchant_In_Transactions()
        {
            _orderVerifications.CheckTransactionMerchantInTransactions_Back(_merchant);
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void CleanUp()
        {
            //In the next line my test result is "Passed"
            if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status == TestStatus.Failed)
            {
                //Do something
            }
            _driver.Dispose();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Even tho the line `Deposit_Money(merchant);` has caused an exception you have caught it, so as far as the runner is concerned there is no problem, all code has gone through with no errors. You know there was a problem, I know there was a problem but the runner doesn't.

If you explicitly fail in the catch, then it will mark it as non-passing.

```
  try
  {
     Deposit_Money(merchant); // this method invokes an exception
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
      Assert.Fail(); /// Explicitly fail the test
      CleanUp();
  }
```

Comment: Ah, you got there first, with a more detailed answer than I did.

Comment: I thought it was a good way but a problem happened. As soon as I invoke Assert.Faild(); my code is no more executing so "CleanUp" method won't be executed.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the constructor rather than inside a `[SetUp]`? Or potentially `[SetUpFixture]`?

Comment: Another option could be if it _has_ to be in constructor is to set a class variable of `SetUpFailed` and additionally check that in your `Cleanup`.

Comment: I don't really remember the reason I use not SetUpFixture now but I know there was one. Thanks, I'll try to use an additional variable.

Comment: The general advice for constructors in NUnit tests is not to do anything but save passed in values. Perform operations on them in methods marked with the SetUp and TearDown attributs. NUnit (particularly V2) may run your constructor more or fewer times than you imagine - depending on what you imagine. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow the exception to be thrown in the test, as strictly speaking, your test has indeed passed.

Remove the error checking in your test, allow the exception to be thrown, and you should see the test result as failed.